# How do I get the text from a QTableView cell into a QlineEdit on click Qt5 C++

Tags: c++, linux, qt5, qtableview, qlineedit

So I have been trying all day to find a working example of how to retrieve the data from a QtableView into a lineEdit as a QString. I think I have tried every example code online and have had zero success, I can not even figure out how to pull the row and column numbers from the tableView. Everything I have tried fails and I get the error that index is a unused parameter. This has got to be something simple that I am missing but I have not used QT or done any C++ programing since version 3 and am completely baffled. mainWindow.cpp is below. Thanks in advance for any help you can give me. BTW everything works fine except for the clicked slot.

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QAbstractTableModel>
#include <QModelIndex>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->setupUi(this);

    // Create a data model for the mapping table from a CSV file
    csvModel = new QStandardItemModel(this);
    csvModel->setColumnCount(2);
    //csvModel->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QStringList() << "Name" << "Number");
    ui->tableView->setModel(csvModel);

    // Open the file 
    QFile file("/home/foo.csv");
    if ( !file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text) ) {
        qDebug() << "File not exists";
    } else {
        // Create a thread to retrieve data from a file
        QTextStream in(&file);
        //Read to end
        while (!in.atEnd())
        {
            QString line = in.readLine();
            QList<QStandardItem *> standardItemsList;
            for (QString item : line.split(",")) {
                standardItemsList.append(new QStandardItem(item));
            }
            csvModel->insertRow(csvModel->rowCount(), standardItemsList);
        }
        file.close();
    }

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}



void MainWindow::on_tableView_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
   qDebug() << "test";

}
```

Header code below

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QStandardItemModel>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_tableView_clicked(const QModelIndex &index);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QStandardItemModel *csvModel;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: Your code seems incomplete.  The slot `on_tableView_clicked` doesn't do anything (all code commented out) and you never connect to it.  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I realized this morning that the slot on_tableView_clicked does nothing. I have been trying to figure out why but no luck so far. I have edited the code to make it more minimal as well as included the header file. Also I setup a new project with the same code but the click slot is still not working.

Comment: Your code is still incomplete and doesn't show the `connect` call.  A [mcve] *must* be complete.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I thought this line of code~~~ui->tableView->setModel(csvModel);~~~would connect the model to the tableview. Guess I need to do some more reading

Comment: Ok so every example I have looked at that show how to connect the model to the view looks like the same code I used     ie   // Connect model to table view:
    ui->tableView->setModel(PhoneBookModel); So I am not sure how to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a basic misunderstanding with regard to how [signals/slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) operate.  Unless you're using the [auto connect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#widgets-and-dialogs-with-auto-connect) feature you need to manually connect a signal to a slot using one of the [`QObject::connect`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect) overloads.  So in your constructor you need something like...

```
connect(ui->tableView, &QTableView::clicked, this, &MainWindow::[on_tableView_clicked);
```

Comment: I was able to fix the connection issue by removing all comments from the read csv code ,changing the model name and changing    csvModel = new QStandardItemModel(this);  to QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel; now I can receive the click event. Not sure why this fixed it but it did. Now I just need to go back and start working on how to get the cell data into the line edit.

Comment: Got it working!!!     Thank you for your time                                                                                                   QString theText;
    if (index.isValid()) {
            theText = index.data().toString();
        }
    ui->lineEdit->setText(theText);